# Python 3. Как переслать файл (изображение) не сохраняя его на диск, а временно сохраняя в оперативной памяти?

Tags: python, requests, ram

Python 3. Задача скачать файлы, и загрузить их в другое место.
Думаю что временно записывать файлы на жесткий диск не лучший вариант.
(по скорости и износу жесткого диска).
Как можно временно подержать файл в оперативной памяти, а затем его отправить?

Скачиваю изображение так

```
r = requests.get(file_url)
```

Можно было бы временно сохранить изображение так:

```
with open('temp_image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Но я хочу узнать вариант как можно сделать аналогичное действие в оперативной памяти.

Обратите внимание

```
type(r.content)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Мой старый код для отправки изображения на сервер выглядит следующим образом

```
b = requests.post(a['upload_url'], files={'photo': open('temp_image.jpg', 'rb')}).json()
```

Файл отправляется в формате _io.BufferedReader

```
file = open("temp_image.jpg", "rb")
print(type(file))   #  <class '_io.BufferedReader'>
print(file)         #  <_io.BufferedReader name='temp_image.jpg'>
```

Насколько я понимаю, нужно что бы бинарные данные в оперативной памяти были преобразованы в _io.BufferedReader , а после этого отправлены

Comment: Мне всегда казалось, что если request'у передать не файловый объект, а просто данные, то он их и отправит. Типа так `requests.post(a['upload_url'], files={'photo': ('temp_image.jpg', r.content)})`

Comment: r.content уже и есть файл и временно сохранен в памяти. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: GrAnd, ваш вариант вызывает ошибку 
`TypeError: open() argument 'mode' must be str, not bytes`

Comment: @ydtop это ваш вариант вызывает такую ошибку, потому что неправильно применен предложенный код.

Comment: Эникейщик, r.content -- не того типа, и если его подставить, то ничего не отправится.

Comment: Ну так забудьте вообще про файлы и решайте вопрос перевода одного типа в другой. А то сейчас как тот математик, который выливает воду из чайника и сводит задачу к предыдущей.

Comment: На самом деле ничего конвертировать далее не надо,  нужно немного изменить код отправки, потому что сейчас он заточен под файл с диска. Т.е. вполне возможно нужно просто отправлять r.